# go back to a specific commit then go back to the present

Tags: git

I'd like to see the file from a specific commit in the past, I'm thinking of `git reset --hard` but I won't be able to see the commits beyond that commit. How do I go back to a commit (together with the state of the files), have a look at the files, the go to the present again?

Comment: You can always just do `git show commit:path/file` to just look at a file.

Comment: I took a look at multiple files, hehe. and I like it better with a text editor. Thanks though, that will be handy next time!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Suppose your current branch is `master` and the old commit is `a1b2c3`, then you can change all the files in your working tree back to the old commit with:

```
git checkout a1b2c3
```

... and return to `master` with:

```
git checkout master
```

This way of hopping about in your git history (i.e. checking out a commit with its object name, also known as its hash or SHA1sum) is very useful for finding a previous good commit for `git bisect`, for example, since it won't move your branches.

One thing to bear in mind is that you'll get a possibly confusing warning when doing this: if you check out a commit from its object name (`a1b2c3`) that will put you into a state known as "detached HEAD", where `HEAD`, which usually represents your current branch, instead points directly to a particular commit.  This isn't something to worry about - it's very useful for moving about in your history - but it does mean that if you create new commits when `HEAD` is detached, they won't move a branch forward.

---

[fork0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410126/fork0) points out in the comment below the potentially useful shortcut `git checkout -`, which will checkout the previous branch or commit that `HEAD` pointed at.

Comment: No problem - I hope the additional comments I added are of use.

Comment: There is a safer way to go back to the previous commit: `git checkout -`. This method uses the checkout logging (.git/logs/HEAD) and can safely determine what was the previous commit.

Comment: @fork0: yeah, I know about `git checkout -`, but in practice I've never found it particularly useful, since I almost always know what branch or commit I want to checkout.  I'll add a note about it to my answer anyway...

Comment: "Detached head" — Linus must be a fan of Mortal Kombat. :)

Answer (score 3):

### If you're using newer version of git(v2.23 or later)

Lets say your branch name is `main`

1. copy the commit hash you want to go using the following command

```
git log --oneline
```

2. use checkout command to go to that specific commit

```
git checkout <commit_hash>
```

3. go back to your initial state(to main branch) using following command

```
git switch main
```

PS:
As you can see i don't use `git checkout` for everything because it has lot of use cases which is confusing for me sometimes. that's why i use the newer `git switch` command to simplify my git workflow.